# How start/stop of SQS Pool works in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, sidekiq

I am running the Ruby on Rails application. I want to receive the message notification when files added to s3 bucket. I am start the SQS Poller to listen the notification from Amazon SQS queue in my application.

I have created SQSPool class as below

```
class SQSPool
  def perform options {}
    queue_name = options['queue_name']

    sqs_queue = SqsQueue.new(queue_name)
         sqs_queue.poller.poll(max_number_of_messages:5, visibility_timeout:15) do |messages, stats|

      messages.each do |message|
        ProcessWorker.perform_async(message)
      end
     end
  end
end
```

Rake task

```
namespace :queues do


  namespace :testing do

    desc "Poll queue"
    task sqstest: :base do
      SqsPoller.new.perform({
        "queue_name" => "sqs-test"
      })
    end  
  end

end
```

I am starting SQS poller using **rake queues:testing:sqstest** and when I stopping the rake command. I get the below error.

```
Interrupt: 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/airbrake-9.5.0/lib/airbrake/rails/net_http.rb:7:in `block in request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/airbrake-9.5.0/lib/airbrake/rack.rb:21:in `capture_timing'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/airbrake-9.5.0/lib/airbrake/rails/net_http.rb:6:in `request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:342:in `request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:74:in `block in transmit'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:126:in `block in session'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:100:in `session_for'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:121:in `session'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:73:in `transmit'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:47:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/content_length.rb:17:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/xml/error_handler.rb:8:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/signature_v4.rb:66:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/transfer_encoding.rb:26:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/helpful_socket_errors.rb:10:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:177:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-sqs-1.23.1/lib/aws-sdk-sqs/plugins/queue_urls.rb:14:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/query/handler.rb:28:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:13:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_pattern.rb:28:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_discovery.rb:78:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:45:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:24:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@my-app/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.76.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
```

Is starting SQS poller in rake command is right? Why I see error when stopping it? How do I start/stop SQS Poller in better way in local and production?

Answer (score 2):

Dealt with this error when running a poller interactively in the terminal and Cntrl+C was exiting the program randomly in the routine. Even for development this is annoying. Assuming that with SQS we want to receive some message and perform some number of tasks on that message before working on the next message, or retry the message later it something failed.

The example below traps the Interrupt, flags the class attribute, and stops polling before the next message, stop polling exits. Essentially allowing any method currently working on the message to complete. Additionally, using StandardError to skip delete if any method raises or all fail to complete.

```
# trap user interrupt and exit, after completing current message task
# frozen_string_literal: false
class SQStrap
  attr_accessor :user_interrupt

  def run!
    self.user_interrupt = false
    Signal.trap('INT') { exit_after_completion }

    credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(CFG['access_key_id'], CFG['secret_access_key'])
    Aws.config.update({ credentials: credentials, region: CFG['region'] })
    poller = Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(CFG['queue'])
    poller.before_request { stop! if user_interrupt == true }
    poller.poll do |msg|
      begin
        tasks(msg.message_attributes)
      rescue StandardError => e
        # error in the routine, skip delete to try the message again later
        pp e
        throw :skip_delete
      end
    end
  end

  def stop!
    puts 'stop polling'
    # kills the poller and process, no need to exit
    throw :stop_polling
  end

  def exit_after_completion
    puts 'exit after completion'
    self.user_interrupt = true
  end

  def tasks(msg)
    event_name = msg.dig('event_name', 'string_value')
    event_time = msg.dig('event_time', 'string_value')
    puts "start: #{event_time} | #{event_name}"

    first = do_this
    second = then_this
    raise 'task failed, retry later' if first != 'done' || second != 'complete'

    puts "completed: #{event_time} | #{event_name}"
  end

  def do_this
    puts 'do_this'
    sleep(3)
    'done'
  end

  def then_this
    puts 'then_this'
    sleep(2)
    # raise 'method 2 failed'
    'complete'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the rake task sends an interrupt signal which in turn raises an `Interrupt` error. This is the error you see on the on the first line of your stacktrace:

```
Interrupt:
```

To end more gracefully you can rescue or trap the interrupt:

```
task :sigint_error do
  begin
    sleep(5000)
  rescue Interrupt
    puts "Stopping!"
  end
end

task :sigint_trap do
  trap("INT") { puts "Stopping!"; exit }
  sleep(5000)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for manual stop.

Comment: And, can you add exception name for better understanding. Or is it all the logs?

Comment: I don't see an any exception name in it. How do I gracefully stop the SQS Poller. How about receive message using this Receive message method. Which is better SQS Poller or Receive Message (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/sqs-example-get-messages.html)?

Comment: If  Receive Message covers the desired functionality, then better use it